# Chrome 6.0 defaults to use thumbnail view

Tags: google-chrome

[Chrome 6](http://www.google.com/chrome) just came out and I updated my version.

My previous setting in Chrome was to have the most visited sites in *list view* show when a new tab opens up.  By default now, thumbnails of the website show up and there isn't an option to switch from thumbnail view to list view as in the previous versions.

How do I switch Chrome 6.0's thumbnail view to list view when a new tab opens up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless an extension brings this back, you cannot switch to list view as they removed the feature.

In the source code of the New Tab page, you'll find:

```
/**
 * Bitmask for the different UI sections.
 * This matches the Section enum in ../dom_ui/shown_sections_handler.h
 * @enum {number}
 */
var Section = {
  THUMB: 1,
  // LIST is no longer used
  RECENT: 4,
  // TIPS is no longer used
  SYNC: 16,
  DEBUG: 32
};
```

The important part is of course "LIST is no longer used".